# How to use std::is_volatile?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-assert

I am trying to disallow a specific operation on volatile types. To accomplish this I am trying to use `std::is_volatile`, but the code below is compiling without errors, which is not what I want.

Why is `is_volatile::value` **false** in the case below?

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
inline void DoStuff(T val) {
    static_assert(!std::is_volatile<T>::value, "No volatile types plz");
    //...
}

int main() {
    volatile char sometext[261];
    DoStuff(sometext);
}
```

Comment: That's just how template argument deduction works -- qualifiers are not part of deduced by-value parameter types. This is essentially the same as: `volatile int src = ... ; int n = src;`. Note how `n` knows nothing about the qualification of `src`. In other words, lvalue-to-rvalue conversion discards qualifiers.

Comment: @KerrekSB maybe you overlooked that an array is given as argument

Comment: @M.M: No, that merely complicates the details a bit, but the core issue remains.

Comment: @KerrekSB: The `volatile` qualifier in this case is deduced, but that is because it's not a top-level qualifier. Your example simplifies the question too far: with just a single level, there's no distinction between top-level qualifiers and qualifiers at other levels. And the crux of the answer (`remove_pointer`) is that you look at the next level, i.e. beyond the top level.

Comment: @MSalters: Yes, that's true.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The problem is that T isn't a `volatile` type at all. It's `volatile char*`. Wait a minute, you say, I see `volatile` right there. True, but consider this: `char* volatile` is a volatile type. `volatile char*` isn't. It's a non-volatile pointer to a volatile `char` array.

Solution: `std::is_volatile<typename std::remove_pointer<T>::type>`

Comment: Better solution: `inline void DoStuff(T* val)`?  Accepting a `T` then stripping the pointer seems less sensible than accepting a `T*`.

Answer (score 9):

When trying to pass the array by value, it decays into a pointer to its first element.

This means that `val` is actually a `int volatile *`. As such, it points to a volatile `int`, but is not itself volatile. Hence, `std::is_volatile` returns false.

You may try taking in the array by reference, or using `std::remove_pointer`.

Answer (score 1):

Because the functions accepts its argument by value, the cv-qualification of the original argument is lost.

Accept it by reference:

```
void DoStuff(T& val)
```

Comment: Considering the example argument is an array, `T* val` might make more sense (but we're missing context)